# InstallShield LaunchAppAndWait syntax

Tags: cmd, installshield

What is the correct syntax for executing a command line through a script with LaunchAppAndWait method. for example if i want to call the command RD:
RD /S /Q D:\Test
what is the correct way to do so?

Answer (score 0):

RD isn't a program that can be launched, it's a CMD command so you'd have to preface that with CMD /C RC...

But my question back to you is, why not use the InstallScript [DeleteDir](http://kb.flexerasoftware.com/doc/Helpnet/installshield14langref/LangrefDeleteDir.htm) function?